# Can Html.Partial() accept a ViewBag to determine the partial view to render?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

So I'm using `Html.Partial()` to render a partial view. This is a very basic MVC app to help me understand partial views and MVC as a whole.

I have a form that has a dropdown which changes what is displayed below said dropdown. If 'One' is selected, 'One' will be displayed, same with 'Two'. This is using a ViewBag which is changed within my controller. However, I want this to be displayed via a partial view. So I've got this `@Html.Partial(ViewBag.Test)`. This doesn't work at all, it gives the CS1973 error.

Here's the full error I'm getting:

Error   CS1973  'HtmlHelper' has no applicable method named 'Partial' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched.

Comment: Please provide the complete error.

Comment: @habib please see my edit

Comment: You already have access to the ViewBag inside the partial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this by casting the contents of `Html.Partial()` to a string:`Html.Partial((string)ViewBag.Test)`. I then put this inside an if statement to check if `ViewBag.Test` is null, because an error occured when ran as `ViewBag.Test` was not assigned to.

This is what I ended up with that worked:

```
@if (ViewBag.Test != null)
{
    @Html.Partial((string)ViewBag.Test)
}
```